# Android BLE cannot get BluetoothGattCharacteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to send data from my Android App to the Bluetooth device, and here is my send_data_code:

```
public boolean sendData(byte[] data) {
    BluetoothGattService btGService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(JumpConstants.UUID_SERVICE_WRITE);
    if(btGService==null){
        Log.d("crx","btGService is null!");
        return false;
    }
    Log.d("crx","btGService="+btGService);
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic write_characteristic = btGService.getCharacteristic(JumpConstants.UUID_CHRACTERISTIC_WRITE);
    Log.d("crx","btGCharacteristic="+write_characteristic);

    if(write_characteristic!=null){
        write_characteristic.setValue(data);
        return mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(write_characteristic);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Sometimes the code works fine but sometimes the "write_characteristic" will be null. And I have no idea why the "write_characteristic" would be null.

Answer (score 0):

This was a hardware problem. The bluetooth hardware I communicated with was not steady, that's why the code sometimes worked fine but sometimes not.